# How to measure the caffeine content of a coffee beer at home?

Tags: specialty-beers, stout

I recently got a winter sampler pack by Sierra Nevada, which had 3 Coffee Stout beers. I've also brewed my own coffee stout for early next year. I was wondering, having tried both, they both have a decent coffee taste, but is there any home science way to find the caffeine content of a coffee beer.

FWIW my homebrew was "dry hopped" with 6 ounces of coffee grounds for two weeks, in a 5gal batch. Not sure if that can help with any calculations.

Let me know if this is off topic, and I can move it to the homebrew SE, or even maybe the chemistry or cooking stack.

Comment: Do you have a [spectrophotometer](http://www.jenway.com/adminimages/A09_010A_Determination_of_Caffeine_in_Beverages_using_UV_Wavelength_Spectroscopy(1).pdf)?

Comment: I suspect the alcohol content of the beer would throw off basic attempts to measure the caffeine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/how-can-you-measure-the-caffeine-content-of-a-liquid-at-home) on the Cooking SE site. Perhaps you can try the approach suggested by Adam Shiemke in the accepted answer. He recommended using ethyl acetate and performing a little home science experiment as detailed [here](http://www.scienceteacherprogram.org/chemistry/Paul00-2.html).